# Get Correct createdAt and modifiedAt date for a file stored in s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, metadata, fs

I have few files stored in s3 and I have to find out the date when file was exactly created. As soon as I download the file, new `created_at` timestamp is generated for the file, but I am able to see correct `created_at` timestamp when I open it in excel or pdf.

I am using `node.js` for fetching files from s3 and need some library to give these dates to me.

I have already tried `xslx`, `fs`, `winattr` and `aws-sdk`.

Comment: Thinking about it, If they're particular types of document like pdf and xlsx then the original created_at stats may be stored in those files themselves rather than as file meta data. You might need to parse your pdf/excel docs to do what you're after. My answer might not do what you need.

Comment: You are right, can you provide something to parse `docx` file metadata?

Answer (score 2):

For local files, e.g. the files after you've downloaded then you can use the Node JS fs.stat function.

This will give you the file stats/metadata details as they are stored by the OS you're running node.js on.

see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback

If you're looking for the date the file was created on Amazon S3 then you can use the Object HEAD rest request.

See [Amazon S3 Object HEAD Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) for further info on that.

It appears Last-Modified is the last modified or creation date of an object, whichever came last. That might give you the granularity that you need. If not you can probably the HEAD command in combination with the versioning commands to figure out the creation date. Find the first version then get the Last-Modified for that first version for the creation date.

See [Amazon S3 Object HEAD Versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/headVersions.html) for further details.

PDF files store their access, created and so forth metadata properties internally as part of their format. You can parse those details using https://github.com/Gottox/node-pdfutils

Excel files and most Microsoft documents do something similar, you might be able to read the created property of the workbook using https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: Thanks for the `node-pdfutils`, but I have tried everything else inclusing fs, and head requests, and I know why they won't work.

Comment: An S3 `HEAD` object request returns a `Last-Modified` header, so named for consistency with standard HTTP behavior.  This is in fact the date/time that the object was written to S3 ("created"), since S3 objects are immutable and cannot actually be "modified" after uploading to a bucket.  Updating object metadata, in fact, does not update the metadata but rather overwrites the object with a copy of itself, along with the new metadata.  This sets `Last-Modified` to "now," but it was not actually modified -- it is technically a new object with a new creation date in S3, a copy of the old.

Comment: Useful info for the OP right there. I've never used Amazon S3, I just went off of the docs. @DileepChirumamila Microsoft document formats ending in .*x, e.g. .docx or .xlsx are XML formatted. Worst case, open the document in a notepad application, find the node with the created date and manually parse this out your self in node using an XML parser.